# Redirect "Not Found" links on web server to directory with sub directory as what the user attempted to reach with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to have whenever the user types a "Not Found" link (using WAMP Server) on my server to redirect to a certain directory with the subdirectory as what the user originally typed.

What I mean is, if the user wants to access `smiskol.com/hello`, and it doesn't exist, then the page gets redirected to `smiskol.com/specific-page/hello` where the page the user tried to access is appended to the end.

I cannot for the life of me figure it out, as I'm new to the syntax of .htaccess. So far I have the following, but it doesn't work:

```
Options -Indexes

Redirect 302 /drop /file-drop

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /short-links/%1 [L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last line, use this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /short-links/$1 [L]
```

Comment: When I used this, I got Internal Server Error

Comment: What does apache's *erro_log* say about that 500 error?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Eduardo Escobar and some extra time, I finally came up with a good solution!

This is the final code I used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/short-links/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /short-links/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/short-links/$1.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

The first chunk redirects to `/short-links/hello` if `hello.php` exists in the `short-links` directory and if the page doesn't exist by itself, while the second redirects the user back to the index page if the page doesn't exist and the short-link doesn't exist. Viola!

Comment: Instead of explicitly hardcoding the server-path (presumably the filesystem  path to the document root, you can use a server variable like `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/short-links/$1.php`.

Comment: I tried something along those lines but it didn't work. This seems to work, however. Thanks!